# Binding Kendo Grid with mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i search the data from by using this subcontractor properties in ActionResult Advacedsearchresult (snapshot is attached)

I get the 1 result bt unable to show in the grid Please help and suggest me how i use this data in kendo grid or bind the data with kendo grid Thanks[image].
[image]
[image]

Comment: `500 internal error` means some error in your server code. Debug and see what is happening at `_AdvancedSearchResult` method. One possible error I can see - you are not passing _cont_ parameter to server.

Comment: so tell me please how i pass the parameter to server

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment since you are not passing the parameter to server, it is failing with *500 Internal Error*. In order to send the parameter from client side you have two ways:-

1) Either send the parameter as route value in `Action` method like this:-

```
read.Action("_AdvancedSearchResult", "ContactList", new { cont = 2 }) //Send param
```

2) You can use the `Data` method to send params:-

`read.Action("_AdvancedSearchResult", "ContactList").Data("additionalData")`

and return the data from JS like this:-

```
function additionalData{
   return {
       cont: 2
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear for help me !!

Comment: @AjayKumar - You're welcome. You can accept the answer if that helped you.

Comment: Of Course sir, your answer is very useful, It helped me,Thanks !!

Comment: @AjayKumar - You're welcome bro, what I meant was please accept the answer, Check how - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/278023, This is how Stack Overflow works and keeps ppl motivated :)